# Ceasar's Cipher: Python

Tags: python, caesar-cipher

I'm going to start off by posting what I have so far then tell you what's happening...

[PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/PRcNdhhw)

```
osalt = ".,!? ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
def decode():
  int = 0
  counter = 0
  msg = requestString("What would you like Decoded?").upper()
  print "Now decoding, '"+msg+"'."
  print "==========Please Wait=========="
  while (int < len(osalt)):
    dmsg = ""
    nsalt = ""
    int += 1
    int2 = 0
    shift = int-1
    while int2 <= len(osalt):
      if int2+shift < len(osalt):
        nsalt += osalt[int2+shift]
      else:
        nsalt += osalt[int2+shift-len(osalt)-1]
      int2 += 1
    for letter in msg:
      index = nsalt.find(letter)
      dmsg += nsalt[index]
    print dmsg
    counter += 1
  print counter
decode()
```

What this is supposed to do is list of 31 possibilities that the encoded message could be when decoded. You put in the encoded message and then it goes through, moving over the salt 1 character at a time... so the second salt would look like this: "Z.,!? ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXY".

The issue I am having is the fact that it isn't moving the salt at all and it ends up printing the input 31 times.

I have looked over my code many times and I cannot figure out how to get it going.

Thanks.

Comment: Two things: (i) "why doesn't this code work" isn't a good fit for SO, please ask more interesting questions, (ii) the above code doesn't follow PEP8 coding/indentation standards -- if you want people to help you, then please make it as easy as possible for them to do so.

Comment: (i)Why doesn't the Salt get moved over in my second while statement?
(ii)Sorry, I didn't realize you could highlight then press the code button... I was just pressing space until it turned to a code block, edited. But I had also provided the necessary pastebin with correct indentation.

Comment: Correct indentation uses 4 spaces. 2 spaces is just confusing to read. Pastebin is a great service but you shouldn't need to use it to ask questions on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, when posting the code make sure it can be executed. Currently you have an undefined function (`requestString`) and inconsistent indentation at the line `print counter`.

As for the question, you have two errors here. First, look at

```
index = nsalt.find(letter)
dmsg += nsalt[index]
```

you're finding the position of a letter in `nsalt` and then just add the very same letter to `dmsg`. That's why you're always printing the same thing. Change one of those to `osalt`.

Second, when you do that, you'll get a `string index out of range` error. This is because your `nsalt` string is actually one character longer than `osalt` and contains a duplicate letter. This is because of the line

```
while int2 <= len(osalt):
```

where you should use just `<`. `int2` starts from 0, and denotes the current position in `nsalt`, so it should finish at `len(osalt) - 1`.

Comment: Thanks for that... But I have one question now.
When it requests an input if I put: 
"?TZWEUWTLWFRE,TWPXA"

One of the results should be: 
"YOUR PROGRAM WORKS."

Instead I get: 
"ZOUR PROGRAM XORKS." as the closest result.

Comment: Nevermind, I removed the -1 from line 18 when I was attempting to get rid of an error... that fixed it.

Thank you for all the help!

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't answer that since I have no idea how you obtained that string.